# cant open .env/activate in docker compose but work in docker build

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

Following is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Upgrade installed packages

RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get install -y libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

WORKDIR /code
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y install python3-venv
RUN apt -y install python3-setuptools libffi-dev python3-dev
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN apt install -y unzip

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential swig

WORKDIR /code
RUN python3 -m venv .env
RUN . .env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN . .env/bin/activate && pip install pyenchant && pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0
RUN apt-get install -y libenchant1c2a

RUN mkdir embeddings
COPY . .
RUN curl -L http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip --output glove.zip
RUN unzip -o glove.zip -d embeddings/

RUN . .env/bin/activate && python nltk_install.py
CMD . .env/bin/activate && python main.py
```

It works when built using `docker build .`

Docker-compose file

```yaml
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
  pythonscripts:
    build: .
    volumes: 
      - "/mnt/d/code/data1/:/code/data/"
```

But when i try with docker-compose using `docker-compose up`. it gives following error:

```
Successfully built 06caf1786bfe
Successfully tagged openbotsdocumentsautomlpythonscripts_pythonscripts:latest
WARNING: Image for service pythonscripts was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating openbotsdocumentsautomlpythonscripts_pythonscripts_1 ... done
Attaching to openbotsdocumentsautomlpythonscripts_pythonscripts_1
pythonscripts_1  | /bin/sh: 1: .: Can't open .env/bin/activate
openbotsdocumentsautomlpythonscripts_pythonscripts_1 exited with code 2
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason youre using a virtual environment in a docker image?

Comment: No but Why it works in docker build but not in docker-compose?

Comment: I dont know but if you dont need to use a virtual environment, and I dont see why you would need to use one in a docker container, then its a problem you dont need to have.

Comment: also why `RUN . .env/bin/activate` and not `RUN .env/bin/activate`?